# Checking multiple user inputs against a list

Tags: python

I'm having an issue on my 2nd path with checking both team 1 and team 2 against the team list, the 2 solutions I've found has required both inputs to be the same to be accepted. Also is a while loop the best way to be going about this? Considering my goal is to not have any typo's because I would like all the data to be stored later on and accessible. Any advice would be appreciated as I am trying to learn.

```
team_list = ["diamondbacks", "braves", "orioles", "red sox", "white sox", "cubs", "reds", "indians", "rockies",
            "tigers", "astros", "royals", "angels", "dodgers", "marlins", "brewers", "twins", "yankees", "mets",
            "athletics", "phillies", "pirates", "padres", "giants", "mariners", "cardinals", "rays", "rangers",
            "blue jays", "nationals"]

if path == 1:  #percentage calculator
   p = int(input("What %? "))
   t = int(input("What is your total? "))
   percent = (t * p) / 100
   print(percent)
if path == 2:  #Bet logging
   while True:
       found_team = False
       try:
           team1 = str(input("Betting Team? "))
           team2 = str(input("Opposing Team? "))
       except ValueError:
           for t in team_list:
               try:
                   if (team1, team2) in team_list:
                       found_team = True
               except ValueError:
                   if found_team == True:
                       print("accepted")
               break
       finally:
           print("failed")
```

Comment: I don't know any reason why ```ValueError:``` will be raised. Also, ```finally``` block will be executed regardless of the "```ValueError```" or not

Comment: `path` is not defined in your code.

Comment: I do not think you need a while loop. A for loop should be enough if you just want to check if the input is in the team_list.

Comment: Some of the code is left out that doesnt involve the current issue just to make it easier to read. Also maybe I misunderstood, I thought ValueError would be raised in the case that anything other then a string was entered? Might be over kill but I feel like its good practice? im not sure. thanks for the advice

Comment: input received from `input()` will be converted to string, no extra `str()` conversion is needed, and no ValueError will be raised in this case as you probably can't input something other than string in prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm having an issue on my 2nd path with checking both team 1 and team 2

Few suggestions:

1. Don't use `try....except` as a replacement for `if....else`. Here, only if `ValueError` is raised, can `except ValueError:` catch it and execute the remaining code.
2. `(x,y)` creates a tuple. And there is no occurrence of `tuple` in the list:

```
>>> print("Type of (x,y)",type((x,y)))
Type of (x,y) <class 'tuple'>
```

3. No need to use `for` loop while using `in` operator to check if a string is in the list.
   Here is some small snippet you might use.

```
found_team=True
while True:
    x=input("Betting Team: ")
    y=input("Opposite Team: ")
    if x in team_list or y in team_list:
        print("Oops! One team is already taken")
    else:
        found_team=True
        break
print("Done!")
```

> Also is a `while` loop the best way to be going about this?

If you want to constantly ask the user till the right input is entered, **yes**. Use a `while` loop to keep asking for user-input till a correct input is entered.

Comment: @Sunnyside391 Most welcome! Consider accepting and upvoting the answers